# Function to check if string contains a vowel

Tags: python

I want to write a function that scans a string for any vowels. What I have written is below

```
def vowel_character(c):
    if c in 'aeiou':
            print("contains a vowel")
            return True 
    else:
            print("contains no vowel")
            return False
```

And it almost works like I want it to. With the asserts here however

```
for c in 'eiyäöaåuo':
    assert vowel_character(c)

for c in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxz':
    assert not vowel_character(c)
```

it returns

```
contains a vowel 
contains a vowel 
contains no vowel
```

why does it give two contains a vowel when it should only give one?

Comment: e and i are vowels, y is not. what’s wrong?

Comment: Currently your function checks if a single character is a vowel. If you want to check if a string contains a vowel, I would move the loop into the function, that only would return `True` or `False` and move `print` and `assert` out of the function.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using assert here since it's normally used as a debugging tool to stop your program when something unexpected happens.

Comment: @Wups Thats what I'm looking for, I want to check "is there a vowel in the string?" and just say yes/no. What do you mean move the loop into the function? :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do `for c in 'eiyäöaåuo'` it tries to loop through each character in the string. So `assert vowel_character(c)` will be called as many times as there are characters in the string.

However, if the assert fails then it will raise an `AssertionError` exception and the loop is aborted. So what is actually happening here is the following:

- Iteration 0: `c = 'e'` => assert True
- Iteration 1: `c = 'i'` => assert True
- Iteration 2: `c = 'y'` => assert False, and so raises an `AssertionError` and exits the program.

Because of this the code doesn't ever reach the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
for c in 'eiyäöaåuo':
    assert vowel_character(c)
```

iterates through the characters in `'eiyäöaåuo'` and asserts that `vowel_character` returns true for each one.

In sequence:

```
assert vowel_character('e')
```

prints "contains a vowel" and the assertion passes.

```
assert vowel_character('i')
```

prints "contains a vowel" and the assertion passes.

```
assert vowel_character('y')
```

prints "contains no vowel" and your assertion fails, ending the execution.

---

> I want it to take the string 'eiyäöaåuo' and since it contains a vowel return True and move on to 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxz' and return False

Here's how you can do that:

```
def contains_vowel(s):
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    return any(ch in vowels for ch in s.lower())

assert contains_vowel('eiyäöaåuo')
assert not contains_vowel('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxz')
```

Comment: What do I need to do in order for the asserts to return
contains a vowel
contains no vowel
?

Comment: Asserts don't return. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I mean how can I write a function so that when I run the asserts gives back the output I am looking for?

Comment: Your function returns true if it is given a, e, i, o or u, and false otherwise. Is that what you want it to return? If not, what do you want it to return?

Comment: I want it to take the string 'eiyäöaåuo' and since it contains a vowel return True and move on to 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxz' and return False

Answer (score 0):

The statement `for c in 'eiyäöaåuo':` is iterating over the string and passing each letter to the function. So on the first three iterations the letters `'e', 'i', 'y'` are passed to `vowel_character`, with the `print` and `return` lines being executed.

On that third iteration though, the function returns `False`, which causes`assert` to raise an `AssertionError`.

Thus the program is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Your code repetitively prints true for a string because you defined function only for a character. Instead of checking for a single char in a string, you could check vowel in whole string. That way you could stop printing again and again for repetitive vowels

Here is a sample code:

```
def vowel_string(s):
    VOWEL = "aeiou"
    for c in s:
        if c.lower() in VOWEL: 
            return True
    return False

s1 = "eiyäöaåuo"
s2 = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxz"

assert vowel_string(s1)
assert not vowel_string(s2)
```